# How to flip an image on canvas when it is edited?

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, flip

I am able to flip an image on the canvas. I am doing it by saving it in a file by using ImageGrab function and rotating that by using ImageOps and placing that on canvas but when the image is edited I mean when objects are rotated or dragged am not able to flip. The drag and rotate part is not there in code.It would be too long if I include it.

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image,ImageGrab
import PIL
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageOps


root = Tk()

def selected1(event):

    if clicked1.get()=="flip horizontal":
        x2=root.winfo_rootx()+canvas.winfo_x()
        y2=root.winfo_rooty()+canvas.winfo_y()
        x1=x2+root.winfo_screenwidth()
        y1=y2+root.winfo_screenheight()
        print("save")
        ImageGrab.grab().crop((x2,y2,x1,y1)).save("saver.jpg")
        im = Image.open("saver.jpg")
        im = ImageOps.mirror(im)
        im.save("saver2.jpg")
        canvas.delete('all')
        global img1
        img1=Image.open("saver2.jpg")
        img1=img1.resize((1225,685),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        canvas.img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)
        canvas_img=canvas.create_image(0,0,image=canvas.img,anchor="nw")

    if clicked1.get()=="flip vertical":
        x2=root.winfo_rootx()+canvas.winfo_x()
        y2=root.winfo_rooty()+canvas.winfo_y()
        x1=x2+root.winfo_screenwidth()
        y1=y2+root.winfo_screenheight()
        print("save")
        ImageGrab.grab().crop((x2,y2,x1,y1)).save("saver.jpg")
        im = Image.open("saver.jpg")
        im = ImageOps.flip(im)
        im.save("saver1.jpg")
        canvas.delete('all')
        global img2
        img2=Image.open("saver1.jpg")
        img2=img2.resize((1225,685),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        canvas.img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
        canvas_img=canvas.create_image(0,0,image=canvas.img,anchor="nw")

def selected2(event):

    if clicked2.get()=="open file":
        global img
        root.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/ROBIN",title="select a file",filetypes=(("image files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
        img=Image.open(root.filename)
        img=img.resize((1225,685),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        canvas.img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        canvas_img=canvas.create_image(0,0,image=canvas.img,anchor="nw")

    if clicked2.get()=="save file":
        x2=root.winfo_rootx()+canvas.winfo_x()
        y2=root.winfo_rooty()+canvas.winfo_y()
        x1=x2+root.winfo_screenwidth()
        y1=y2+root.winfo_screenheight()
        print("save")
        ImageGrab.grab().crop((x2,y2,x1,y1)).save("checker.jpg")

    if clicked2.get()=="exit":
        root.quit()



canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

rectangles=[]


canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

options1=[
     "select flip",
     "flip horizontal",
     "flip vertical",
]

clicked1=StringVar()
clicked1.set("select flip")

drop1=OptionMenu(root,clicked1,*options1,command=selected1)
drop1.place(relx=1,x=-1,y=1,anchor=NE)

clicked2=StringVar()
clicked2.set("select")

options2=[
    "select",
    "open file",
    "save file",
    "exit",
]

drop2=OptionMenu(root,clicked2,*options2,command=selected2)
drop2.place(relx=1,x=-1,y=40,anchor=NE)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you mean you have a background image, some onverlay on it (canvas objects) and you want  to flip background and objects? If this is the case you need to redraw your objects are their new position in the "flipped" background.

Comment: Actually which part of the screen/window do you want to captured using `ImageGrab.grab()`?